# How can I run the main file with flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to run the server (it's about oauth2):

The main file looks like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = True
    app.secret_key = 'development'
    app.config.update({
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'sqlite:///test.sqlite'
    })
    app = create_server(app)
    app.run()
```

However, I am getting this error:

> Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'hello'. Use 'FLASK_APP=hello:name' to specify one.

I executed the following commands in terminal:

```bash
export FLASK_APP=server.py` and 
export FLASK_APP=main.py
```

After that, I tried rerunning with `flask run`

Again, I am getting this error:

> Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'main'. Use 'FLASK_APP=main:name' to specify one.

Comment: In your terminal use: set FLASK_APP=main.py, then: flask run. "main.py" is the name of your python file and the keyword set it works in pycharm and vscode. Let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: Yep, open your terminal in vscode or pycharm, go to the directory of your project and type the commands above.

Comment: You forgot the keyword "set". If this keyword doesn't work use "export".

Comment: do not use "export" in vscode, use "set". Also, I recommend you to use the boiler plate code from the documentation of flask, what you have is a bit of a mess.

Comment: I suggest reading the [flask quickstart guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/). This should answer all your questions about the basics of creating and running a flask app.

Comment: I'm not sure but you should run directly `python server.py`. And if you want to run with `flask run` then DON'T put code in `if __name__ == '__main__':` because it will `import` this file and it will skip all code in `if __name__ == '__main__':`. And i may need to use `FLASK_APP=server:app` which means to use file`server.py`, object `app` (instance of `Flask()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run it directly

```
python server.py
```

---

And if you want to use `flask run` then you would have to put all (except `app.run()`) before `if __name__ == '__main__':` because `flask run` will `import` this file and `import` will skip code inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`

```
# ... other code ...

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'development'
app.config.update({
    'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'sqlite:///test.sqlite'
})
app = create_server(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And it will need `export FLASK_APP=server:app` because you want to run file `server.py` and use instance of `Flask()` with name `app`

```
export FLASK_APP=server:app

flask run
```

Because code uses standard name `app` so you could skip it in `export`

```
export FLASK_APP=server

flask run
```

You can also run without `export`

```
flask --app server run
```

Comment: if you run server and client in console/terminal then you should see more useful error message in console/terminal. `Internal Server Error` often is created when there is problem with database. This server uses some database `SQLite` but it needs to create this database manually before start.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'development'
app.config.update({
   'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'sqlite:///test.sqlite'
})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="5000", debug=True)
```

Comment: You have to create flask routes. Are you getting this error in the browser?

Comment: First what address are you typing in the browser, second create routes.   @app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello Word</h1>'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

But I recommend you to start with the basics before work with databases. Try to render HTML templates, use bootstrap, etc. You are running here. Anyway, this boilerplate works for me.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
# Key for Forms
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'


# SQL DATABASE AND MODELS
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db)


class Puppy(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'puppies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello Puppy!</h1>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Copy paste the code as it is. It should work. Also kill the process if by chance you are running already something in 127.0.0.1:5000.